# How to populate dynamic data in azure pipeline's custom task.json input options

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-extensions, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am developing a task where i need to populate the input fields with dynamic options e.g. via an API calls and show it to user in Pipeline's TASK UI.

I can see we have `type : connectedServices:*` , my assumption(Not sure if i am right) is that connectedServices only refers to connection defines in Azure DevOps Connection.

How can i call TypeScript function that fetching dynamic Values and populating it for user via task.json file ?

Comment: Did you ever manage to load input's values dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can populate dynamic data in azure pipeline's custom task.json input options with service endpoints.

Service endpoints are a way for Azure DevOps to connect to external systems or services. Here is a [how-to guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops) about how to create a service endpoint.

Comment: this 'how to guide' is mostly concerning calling a Custom Service define in Azure Devops. However my doubt is how to populate data by calling a Function in the TypeScript and Source Binding the field in Task.json.(if possible)
I would prefer to do source binding without relying on Azure's "Custom Service Endpoint" as i need to truncate the output from service as per business requirement.